# python re, find expression containing an optional group

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression that can have either from:

```
(src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy)
(src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy "optional string")
```

These expressions occur within a much longer string (they are not individual strings). I am having trouble matching both expressions when using `re.search` or `re.findall` (as there may be multiple expression in the string).

It's straightforward enough to match either individually but how can I go about matching either case so that two groups are returned, the first with `src://path/...` and the second with the `optional string` if it exists or `None` if not?

I am thinking that I need to somehow specify OR groups---for instance, consider:

The pattern `\((.*)( ".*")\)` matches the second instance but not the first because it does not contain `"..."`.

```
r = re.search(r'\((.*)( ".*")\)', '(src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy)'
r.groups()  # Nothing found
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

While `\((.*)( ".*")?\)` matches the first group but does not individually identify the `"optional string"` as a group in the second instance.

```
r = re.search(r'\((.*)( ".*")?\)', '(src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy "optional string")')
r.groups()
('src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy "optional string"', None)
```

Any thoughts, ye' masters of expressions (of the regular variety)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to make the first `*` [non-greedy](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy):

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "(src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy)"
>>> string2 = \
... '(src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy "optional string")'
>>> re.findall(r'\((.*?)( ".*")?\)', string2)
[('src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy', ' "optional string"')]
>>> re.findall(r'\((.*?)( ".*")?\)', string)
[('src://path/to/foldernames canhave spaces/file.xzy', '')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `"` aren't usually allowed to appear in file names, you can simply exclude them from the first group:

```
r = re.search(r'\(([^"]*)( ".*")?\)', input)
```

This is generally [the preferred alternative to ungreedy repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), because tends to be a lot more efficient. If your file names can actually contain quotes for some reason, then ungreedy repetition (as in agf's answer) is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for alternative with efficiency in mind. I found that this method is about 8x faster but does have caveats.

Comment: @BFTM what caveats do you mean? In the sense that you have filenames containing `"`?

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that the first expression cannot have contain `"`. In the case above it's a nice solution because filenames won't contain `"` but the non-greedy search seems to be more general (but slower).